# Fluentd - Configure CPU and Memory requests and limits based on nodepool or namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I am using fluentd as daemonset in my cluster. That cluster has 30 nodes, but 5/30 nodes receive a big quantity of requests. My fluentd pods reach CPU Limit only for those 5 nodes. Is there a way to set CPU and Memory request and limits based on nodepool or namespace?

Comment: Fluentd does not perform very well. Organizations typically change to e.g. FluentBit for this reason.

Comment: You can create a [LimitRange](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/#:~:text=A%20LimitRange%20is%20a%20policy,per%20PersistentVolumeClaim%20in%20a%20namespace.) object within a namespace but this will only be used if deployments, daemonsets, etc. within that namespace don't set their on resource limits.